# compatibility issues: "Bad Address" at compile time

Tags: python, c++

I'm currently trying to build a large software project (fortran/python/c++, build with CMake) in a new environment that it was not intended for.
Most errors that I get during compile time can be resolved trivially by changing around a couple of `#include` statements, adding or removing `std::` in some places and adding some include guards here and there. However, now I ran into an error that baffles me:

```
/cvmfs/sft.cern.ch/lcg/contrib/gcc/4.9.3/x86_64-slc6/include/c++/4.9.3/memory:79:24: error: /cvmfs/sft.cern.ch/lcg/contrib/gcc/4.9.3/x86_64-slc6/include/c++/4.9.3/functional: Bad address
#  include <functional>
```

with different files and headers, but always `Bad Address` - friend Google did not help me understand this error message.

What is happening here? Whas does `Bad Address` mean, and why do I get it during compilation?

Comment: I could find something in the [GNU C library](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Error-Codes.html).

Comment: This looks like a runtime error to me... asking Google for "EFAULT" makes me believe that actually CMake crashes here... but why would that happen?